# Check input from user is a url in C?

Tags: c, regex, linux

How can i check that a user has input a url into the terminal for my application? Is there some sort of regex i can use?

I am getting the input from the terminal in Linux and storing it in a char str[100] variable.

EDIT*
I need to check that they can only enter a URL that actually exists, if that is possible.

Comment: What cases do you need to check the URL for e.g. is http://stackoverflow.com/rubbish valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this regular expression. It does not allow for the ?.... at the end though.

```
^https?://(((0|([1-9][0-9]{0,1}))(\.(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,1}))){3})|([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_@\.&+*"\'\(\),]|(%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))*(\.([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_@\.&+!*"\'\(\),]|(%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))*))*))(/|((/([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_@\.&+!*"\'\(\),]|(%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))*))*))$
```

PS:  I constructed it from an RFC

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT* I need to check that they can only enter a URL that actually exists, if that is possible.

You could make a HEAD request to the given URL and check returned http status code. If you ignore temporary failures it should tell you whether the resource is accessible, e.g., [make http HEAD request in C using libcurl](https://gist.github.com/cf7dd1eb3ae6e39564a5).

---

> How can i check that a user has input a url into the terminal for my application? Is there some sort of regex i can use?

[rfc 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) provides the regular expression for breaking-down a *well-formed* URI reference into its components:

```
/^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/
```

Note two thing:

- it doesn't validate input
- it is already complex

To validate an url you could split an input using the above regex and check that each part is valid *for your particular case* e.g., that scheme is `'http'`, query & fragment are empty, etc. The code should be simpler to understand and debug than one giant opaque regex.

Comment: Agreed. Far better to use a generic component split and then validate the pieces. (What's more, properly validating things like host names requires more than just string processing.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard lib has some regex functions (man regex). You can also use 3rd party libs like PCRE.